# After reboot allocated node gets commissioned again

Tags: juju, maas

si had set up a maas with juju and deployed Openstack into it for testing. During my vacation i shut down all computers. Afterwards i started at first the maas server, then the node where juju was bootstrapped and juju-gui was deployed to. Sadly the node got commissioned again and so all my deployments are gone.

I decomissioned the according node from the maas and bootstrapped it again. Afterwards i tested again juju bootstrapping the node, shutting down both nodes and starting them in the same order again. The Juju node gets commisioned again.

After bootstrapping everything looked fine in the MAAS GUI (node was set to allocated to root, which was also the case after the restart) and also the JUJU GUI was available and juju status worked fine.

Before my vacation i also had some other nodes deployed through juju. They all seem to be still available and have not been commisioned again.

Do you have any ideas what might have happened? Is there any issue with a bootstrapped juju node and the commisioning?

Any help or hints on what i could check are appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: Additional Information: I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: I set up the maas again with Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04.1 and now it seems as if the recommisioning does not occur anymore.

Comment: So was this a one-off issue or has this shown up again?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "i started at first the maas server, then the node where juju was bootstrapped " do you mean you've started the node juju was using by powering it on or by using the MAAS web UI to start it? If it's the latter, then the node *will* get recomissioned (that's by design, as you're essentially telling MAAS "I don't want to use this node anymore as configured, I need it clean to use it for something else"), if it's the former the node should *not* get recommissioned. Please, file a bug if you've observed a different behavior.